# beforeEach hook not mutating context correctly

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have some step definitions that need to be placed relative to others, so I use context to warn the test writer if they are not writing the test correctly.

**cucumber**

```
Scenario: doesn't need fixture
  Given I am "admin"
  And I am logged in

Scenario: uses fixture
  Given I am "admin"
  And I use the fixture "foo.json"
  And I am logged in
```

**js**

```
beforeEach(function () {
  this.isLoggedIn = false;
  cy.fixture('fixtures.json').as('fixtures');
});

given('I am {string}', function(username) {
  this.username = username;
});

given('I am logged in', function () {
  cy.request('/auth/login');
  this.isLoggedIn = true;
  // etc...
});

given('I use the fixture {string}', function(fixtureName) {
  if (this.isLoggedIn) throw new Error('You should declare fixtures before logging in');

  this.data = this.fixtures[fixtureName];
});
```

If I do some console logging in the `beforeEach` hook, I see that `this.isLoggedIn` is set to `false` before every test. However, if I log the same thing in my step definition the context doesn't seem to change.

[`as` is async](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/as.html#as-is-asynchronous), so I thought maybe it was some race condition preventing context from being set, but trying to wait for `cy.fixture` to finish in a hook like this

```
beforeEach(function() {
  return Promise.all([
    cy.fixture('fixtures'),
    cy.fixture('users')
  ]).then((fixtures, users) => {
    this.fixtures = fixtures;
    this.users = users;
    this.isLoggedIn = false;
  })
});
```

then cypress just tells me I [can't use a promise in a hook](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/error-messages.html#Cypress-detected-that-you-returned-a-promise-in-a-test-but-also-invoked-one-or-more-cy-commands-inside-of-that-promise)...

How do you correctly reset context in hooks?